# Using Registry with JAVA in Mac OS

Tags: java, macos, registry, osx-server

I have written a **Java** desktop application in **Windows** platform that is using the **Windows Registry** to save the application information like location of the application, time-period (like free-trial up to 30 days ) etc.

Now, i want to create the same java application to run on **Mac OS**. Although the most of the java code will be same but i am not sure about the Registry concept in Mac OS.
Is there any ***Registry in Mac Os*** like in Windows platform. If yes, how can i use the Mac Registry with JAVA to write application information?

Regards,

Arun Kumar

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `java.util.prefs` mechanism is the cross-platform way to approach this sort of thing.  On Windows it's backed by the registry, on Mac it's backed by `.plist` files in `~/Library`, and on Linux and friends it's backed by files in `~/.java`, but the API you use to access the information is the same on all platforms.

Comment: Thanks for you reply. I have goggled .plist files are the Mac version of preference files. Similar to .ini files on Windows. So in actual they are the Property list files for a software application. Are .plist files are really the alternative of Windows Registry in Mac-OS?

Comment: They are a standard format that native mac applications use to store preferences. But the point is that you don't need to know or care about that, just use the Java `Preferences` API and it will store the data in whatever way makes most sense on the platform. You don't need any specific code for Windows, Mac, etc.

Comment: There is no single central "registry" as such on Mac but the plist files in `~/Library/Preferences` do the same job. Each application has its own plist file and the format can represent an arbitrarily deep tree structure of data using nested "dictionaries" (sets of key/value pairs where the value can be, among other things, another dictionary).

Comment: One more thing Ian, Could you please suggest any tutorial or sample of Java Preferences API that is writing/reading to/from PLIST files in Mac-Os?

Comment: _Any_ tutorial will do, the whole point of the preferences API is that you use the same Java code regardless of which platform you're running on. You could try [this one from Oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/lang/preferences.html) for starters.

Comment: @IanRoberts - Broken link my friend.