# Solutions for License/Key java application

Tags: java

i'm developping an application and i want users to use a key associated with period of time if they want to use it. (Giving them a period of time, during this period they can use the software, after that they can't use it or they can put another key, i heard about using registry?).

- First i would like to have a solution without internet connection at
  all (they put a key, and they can use it until the given time). How
  can i do that and also how can i know when the period is over? (The
  computer time is not enough reliable right? )
- Second i would like to have a solution where the key is checked when the user enter it. Then the webservice (php page for example) return 
  the date of expiration and store it somewhere.
- Third i use internet every time, when the key is entered and every time the software is launched.

I really would prefer having a solution matching the first scenario i described. But in your opinion which one is the best, and what to use

Thanks a lot for your advices!

Pierre

Comment: I think it depends on what platform you want to use. I searched this and found a CROSS-PLATFORM solution. Pretty cool http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12478075/using-registry-with-java-in-mac-os

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10548510/how-to-create-license-for-my-java-software

Comment: Thanks, you are right i wanted it on both mac and windows, i take note!

Answer (score 0):

I've not used it myself but take a look at [Protection!](http://www.jproductivity.com/products/protection/developer.htm)